# Select everything besides the Max(date) for each group

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a table where I would like to pull everything besides the max dates for each groupID.
Is there an easy way to do it?

here is what i am trying to do:

```
SELECT 
groupId, 
Types,
MAX(Dates) as date

FROM TableData

Where Dates < Max(dates)

GROUP BY 
groupId, 
Types

//The table looks as follows:
ID      |   GroupID | Date
1       |     A     | 10-10-2020 -> don't show
2       |     A     | 09-10-2020
3       |     A     | 08-10-2020
4       |     B     | 10-10-2020 -> don't show
5       |     B     | 09-10-2020
6       |     B     | 08-10-2020


//Expected result:
GroupID | Date
  A     | 09-10-2020
  A     | 08-10-2020
  B     | 09-10-2020
  B     | 08-10-2020
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a classic situation where the use of [window functions](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/) can come to the rescue!

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT 
    group_id, 
    dates,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY group_id
                        ORDER BY dates DESC) AS rn
  FROM table_data
) AS t
WHERE rn != 1
ORDER BY group_id, dates DESC;
```

Can I urge you not to use a keyword as an alias - use something like `my_date` or `the_date` instead - it helps readability and is less prone to problems when debugging!

Also, please include your SQL Server version in your questions.

Finally, you could make things a lot easier for those trying to help you if you provided a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) with your tables and data - this allows those answering to test their replies and helps eliminate duplication of effort (include the fiddle data in the question also).

Comment: I might be tempted to use `RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER` if the date can appear more than once - as this would only remove the first row that the contains the max date. Other than that, this is the route I would take.

Comment: @WorldWideDBA - you are correct - I did make the implicit assumption that the date would be unique! Perhaps the OP can enlighten us?

Comment: Hello @WorldWideDBA, when I try your solution I get an error near The where clause. I will update my question with a the "real life" code im trying to write. And you are right, I should've been more specific

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I just updated my question, for some reason the query but no results are coming back. could it be due to the json? it works fine when i do a normal select or filtering with the json row

Comment: @MishMish - could you please provide a fiddle with your table structure as it is currently (esp. with the JSON/JSONB field - also include any queries you have tried) and a small sample of your data - without these we are flying blind!

Comment: @Vérace the above suggestion actually worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: Row_Number would be non-determinate as world wide dba says, I would suggest just  returning the max date over the window, and then check to see if the date is less than that